# Kusto Query 2 Tables with different schemas

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kusto-explorer

I have 2 tables in separate clusters with different schemas. I would like to write a Kusto query get their message field (which they have in common) and then store the result. I have this query right now, but it doesn't show results from table2:

```
.set stored_query_result RESULT 
<| cluster("cluster1.eastus").database("db1").table1
| union cluster("cluster2.westus").database("db2").table2 
| where id == 123
```

Edit: This works for me

```
.set stored_query_result RESULT 
<| union cluster("cluster1.eastus").database("db1").table1, cluster("cluster2.westus").database("db2").table2 
| where id == 123
```